# how to startactivity or call intent in fragment?

Tags: android-intent

when i start the apps, and enter the button, it come out the error"unfortunately, intenttest has stopped.

Fragment_Main.jave  code as follow

```
public class Fragment_Main extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
EditText studentID;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false); 
         studentID = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         Button submit = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         submit.setOnClickListener(this);
            return root;
     }

     @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         Fragment frag = new Average();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Average.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID", studentID.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,frag).commit();
        }}
```

average.jave code as follow

```
public class Average extends Fragment {
TextView studentInfo;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     }
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_average, container, false);
         studentInfo = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();//取得活動的Intent
            studentInfo.setText("學號:" + intent.getStringExtra("ID"));
            return root;
     }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Fragment you can start activity using following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),yourclassname.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: should i delete the code as follow

Fragment frag = new Average();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,frag).commit();

Comment: If you trying to call Fragment then it's right but if you wants to call Activity ,you have to replace your code.